# Is there any way to recover unsaved notepad++ docs?

Tags: windows, notepad++, crash, troubleshooting, file-recovery

I had to immediate shut down, and I lost about 20 unsaved tabs, is there any way to recover these?

Comment: notepad++ bydefault saves the recent documents. so that if you do not change this settings it may be chance to get unsaved tabs otherwise not.

Answer (score 96):

#### Is there any way to recover unsaved files?

Notepad++ will autosave if configured to do so.

- The default "Backup path" is `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\backup` (or `<Notepad++ install directory>\backup`). Look in this directory for any backup files.
- Goto menu "Settings" > "Preferences" > "Backup" tab to see your configuration.
- If "Enable session snapshot and periodic backup" has been checked then there will a "Backup path" configured.

[image]

---

#### When was the "Session snapshot and periodic backup" feature introduced?

In version 6.6.x:

> As a reminder, the main feature of v6.6.x is Session snapshot & periodic backup - user won't be asked to save unsaved file as he quits Notepad++, and on startup Notepad++ restores the unsaved file and unsaved untitled document of last session. Such periodic backup of unsaved files will protects your data from the PC crashing or power outage.
>
> You can always turn off this feature to get back the old behaviour:
> http://notepad-plus-plus.org/assets/images/sessionSnapshot.png

Source [Notepad++ 6.6.2 released](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.6.2-release.html)

Answer (score 47):

I had also lost my one notepad++ file but I was able to recover that file from following location:

```
C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup
```

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: This answer is useful because this is the default directory for this purpose - so if anyone just wants to go directly for the prize, without even opening Notepad++, this is probably it.

Comment: This saved a database creation script I was shitting squirrels about losing. It's worth mentioning that for me, unsaved files were backed up there but saved ones were not.

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: This will work (via copy paste) vs your pseudo path:  C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming

Comment: `%APPDATA%` is what you should be using (as users folder might not be located at `C:\Users`)

Answer (score 18):

In case if Notepad++ was not able to create the backup file and had crashed, it tries to create the *.dump files that could be found at the following path:

```
C:\Users\<windowsusernamehere>\AppData\Local\Temp\N++RECOV\
```

Comment: In my case for some reason it had issues with a lot of files that I have been using several days and they were not in the backup path but they were in this path.

Comment: Worth noting that even if your files have their name mangled and end in .DUMP, notepad++ seems to be able to open them just fine.

Comment: Mine was in %AppData%\Roaming\Notepad++\backup