# where can I find the folder where notepad++ stores unsaved tabs?

Tags: notepad++, path, session

My laptop crashed one month ago. The HDD has not been damaged and I can read it from my new laptop.

However, I'd like to restore my unsaved tabs in Notepad++, but can't find them back; I can't even find in which path they were stored. I found the config.xml file stating that RememberLastSession was set to yes, but nothing else.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks a lot

pp

EDIT: Thanks, but I've read this thread before posting and could not find the folders specified in the thread. As the flag RememberLastSession was turned on, could you tell me in which file the path is stored?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/975594/is-there-any-way-to-recover-unsaved-notepad-docs

Comment: no, I've read this thread before posting.

Comment: You may have read it the linked answer but you have not specified how your question is different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the session.xml file? It stores the parameters of the tabs that are stored by N++ including the backup location.

For me the active tabs were stored in the ..\backup\ folder. If you've already looked there it's likely you're not going to find your files.

Comment: No needs to look at the session.xml file, this info is present (and updatable) in `Settings > Preferences > Backup`

Comment: The poster indicate they had read a thread pointing to that settings screen already. I was offering a (however unlikely) alternative to locating their files.