# notepad++: how to recover lost tabs

Tags: notepad++

My Windows XP machine had blue-screen crash and when I restarted, the notepad++ configuration was lost - when I started it, it said something like *"Do you want to recover your config.xml?"* Unfortunatelly, I just clicked Cancel, because I am used to dismiss all annoying things that pop up without actually reading them. After this, notepad++ started totally fresh with just one tab open (instead of ~ 100 which I had), and with different font size.

**Is there a way to recover the open tabs?** I know the files are stored in cache but I want the tabs open as they were. Is it possible?

PS: this happened second time already! How is it possible that notepad++ completely loses configuration upon system crash??? No other program does that!

Comment: It would have been if you had recovered that config file... But now you can't recover it anymore. You may want to do something about blindly clicking boxes without properly reading them though, its one of the ways spyware gets installed.

Comment: @LPChip spyware? But from where? Something must launch these boxes first, something that has permission to instal.

Comment: The install often doesn't have permission...until someone blindly clicks the button to permit it. :)

Comment: @EBGreen which install are you talking about? Who is the program asking me in the box? What situation you talk about?

Comment: That all depends on which malware is asking to install. The point is read messages or accept the consequences of not reading them.

Comment: @Tomas a website looking like notepad++ could infect you. A website with exploit could install software. Given that you use XP, you are already far behind when it comes to security.

Comment: Have a look at the Recycle Bin, you might be in luck.

Comment: @harrymc unfortunatelly nope :/ Thanks

Comment: In future, use Sessions - [How can I make Notepad++ remember all instances of itself from last session?](//superuser.com/a/795146)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to recover unsaved notepad++ docs?](https://superuser.com/questions/975594/is-there-any-way-to-recover-unsaved-notepad-docs)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. I didn't lose any files, I am asking about lost configuration (open tabs). The asker of the other question probably lost files, but we don't know really, since his question is very brief and unclear and he didn't even bother to respond to people who answered.