# How to recover unsaved notepad++ file in windows 10

Tags: notepad++, recovery

I haven't configured backup path.

I am using version 5.9.8.

I was editing a new file which was not saved even once and my laptop crashed. Is there a way to recover it?

[image]

Comment: Normally Notepad++ just reopens with all the open files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to recover unsaved notepad++ docs?](https://superuser.com/questions/975594/is-there-any-way-to-recover-unsaved-notepad-docs)

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Notepad++ (Release Date: 2012-01-05)?